# Solve the ode $\frac{dx}{x^2-yu}=\frac{dy}{y^2-xu}=\frac{du}{u^2-xy}.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the ode
$$\frac{dx}{x^2-yu}=\frac{dy}{y^2-xu}=\frac{du}{u^2-xy}.$$

Other problems being easy, while this really troubles me...One try is $$\frac{d(x^2)}{x^3-xyu}=\cdots$$ While it is not easy to get some first integrals.

Comment: Hint:try to get separately $dy/dx$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ only, $dy/du$ in terms of $y$ and $u$ only etc..

Comment: @Arian Is this a hint, a hunch, a guess, or whatnot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this well know
$$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{e}{f}\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{a-c}{b-d}=\dfrac{c-e}{d-f}$$
since 
$$\dfrac{dx}{x^2-yu}=\dfrac{dy}{y^2-ux}=\dfrac{du}{u^2-xy}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \dfrac{dx-dy}{x^2-y^2+xu-yu}=\dfrac{dy-du}{y^2-u^2+xy-xu}$$
so
$$\dfrac{d(x-y)}{(x-y)(x+y+u)}=\dfrac{d(y-u)}{(y-u)(y+u+x)}$$
so
$$\dfrac{d(x-y)}{x-y}=\dfrac{d(y-u)}{y-u}$$
then we have
$$\dfrac{x-y}{y-u}=C_{1}
$$
then simaler have
$$\dfrac{y-z}{z-x}=C_{2}$$